# PHP frontend for existing git reposetories

Tags: gratis, software-development, php, gui, git

I'm looking for a frontend interface for git repo's written in PHP. I would like the software to meet these requirements,

- Gratis
- Works with existing repositories ([GitPHP](http://www.gitphp.org/) will not work because it states in their [installation page](http://www.gitphp.org/installation/), "Repository Prep: These must be bare repositories. GitPHP will not read working copy repositories (the .git hidden folder in your source tree)."
- Works with PHP (it can also work with Python and MySQL if needed)
- GUI
- In active development (nothing ancient, please:)
- Does not require root access or the like on the system (Works nicely on shared hosts like cPanel, [Phabricator](http://www.phabricator.org/) sadly does not:/ "shared hosts and unusual environments are not supported")

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with [Interfaces, frontends, and tools - Git SCM Wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools) already? Especially the section [Web Interfaces](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Web_Interfaces) should be useful in this context. From that list, [GitList](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist) looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a recommendation from Izzy, I'm now using GitList. It's simple to install and the only configuration is basically setting up a config file and a cache folder (does not even need a database:). It has a great interface and the git repositories can be anyway on the server (does not have to be in the same directory). It meets all my requirements and more. It's open source under the BSD License. It has an easy to use interface and works with new repositories as well as ancient ones. GitList uses just Git, PHP, & Apache - no need for anything else. It is in active development (24 commits this year). It works great on my shared host (make sure your host provides git through the command line, mine does).

## [GitList](http://gitlist.org) ([Open Source](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist))

> GitList is an elegant and modern web interface for interacting with multiple git repositories. It allows you to browse repositories using your favorite browser, viewing files under different revisions, commit history, diffs. It also generates RSS feeds for each repository, allowing you to stay up-to-date with the latest changes anytime, anywhere. GitList was written in PHP, on top of the Silex microframework and powered by the Twig template engine. This means that GitList is easy to install and easy to customize. Also, the GitList gorgeous interface was made possible due to Bootstrap.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Multiple repository support
> - Multiple branch support
> - Multiple tag support
> - Commit history, blame, diff
> - RSS feeds
> - Syntax highlighting
> - Repository statistics
>
> [image: GitList UI]